# Error while using javaxt

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, metadata

I am having a problem when using javaxt in my android application.

Basically what I did is, added the javaxt jar file as a library to my project and configured the `build.gradle` and the `settings.gradle` so the the javaxt jar file will be compiled. In my java class I am importing the `javaxt.io.Image` and my actual code is the following:

```
Image image = new Image("/storage/extSdCard/gps/gps_001.jpg");
double[] gps = image.getGPSCoordinate();
```

When I am trying to build my project the build is failing and the error is the following:

```
Error:(200, 27) error: cannot access RenderedImage class file for java.awt.image.RenderedImage not found Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Anyone experiencing the same problem or have experienced the problem and solved it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your source code or your library uses `java.awt.image.RenderedImage`, which does not exist on Android. `javaxt.io.Image` definitely refers to `RenderedImage`.

Note that there is no sign that the authors of this library offer Android compatibility. You may find it easier to solve your problem using a library known to work on Android.

Comment: You're right. I checked the code of the Image JAVA class found in the javaxt library and basically it relies on java.awt.image.*. Will have to find an alternate way to access the meta data than. Thanks for your help.